# HttpWebResponse header location does not include querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code:

```
        string getCustomerTokenUrl = "someurl?vi=7&vt=" + encryptedToken + "&DPLF=Y";
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(getCustomerTokenUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        objRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = objRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers["location"]);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

When I run the code, I get a value from the location header, however it is missing an expected query string.

What I get:

```
http://anotherurl.com/api/SSO/autoSWLLoginCT
```

What I see in the chrome developer tools if I go directly to the url stored in getCustomerTokenUrl (in the response location header):

```
http://anotherurl.com/api/SSO/autoSWLLoginCT?ct=dabe6dcd25385b7a77e3a1587cef9e6fee20e7af0952a4691ef2169ef9ec6704367626a647c07473ec2b3c98746b79cc66a646857c85930042a616db69442ca5
```

Is there something I am configuring wrong that would cause the query string to be truncated?

Comment: Does it otherwise locate the resource correctly? Perhaps `response.RequestUri.Query` to just read the values.

Comment: wouldn't response.RequestUri refer to the url I have stored in getCustomerTokenUrl, not the location url stored in the header?

Comment: `response.ResponseUri.Query` don't know how I typed that

Comment: When I use response.ResponseUri it references the initial url from getCustomerTokenUrl, not the new redirect url unfortunately.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing `req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;` and then getting the `response.ResponseUri`. It seems to me that it might be on the way to change the `location` header.